# Unix/Perl - Remove contents of a file before a pattern

Tags: perl, file, unix

I have a file like this

```
### SECTION 1 ###
data data
data data
### SECTION 2 ###
data data 
data data
```

Now I want everything before **SECTION 2** to be removed.

How can I do this in Perl or Unix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -ne '$m = 1 if $_ =~ /SECTION 2/ ; next unless $m ; print $_;' filename > newfilename
```

Comment: For what it's worth, explicit use of `$_` is often superfluous (and harder to read, IMHO).  `$m=1 if /SECTION 2/; next unless $m; print;` is semantically identical to this answer.

Answer (score 6):

To edit the file in-place:

```
perl -i -ne 'print if /SECTION 2/..0' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -pi -e '$_ = "" unless /SECTION 2/ .. /(*FAIL)/' file
```